# Ruby design pattern: How to make an extensible factory class?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

Ok, suppose I have Ruby program to read version control log files and do something with the data. (I don't, but the situation is analogous, and I have fun with these analogies). Let's suppose right now I want to support Bazaar and Git. Let's suppose the program will be executed with some kind of argument indicating which version control software is being used.

Given this, I want to make a LogFileReaderFactory which given the name of a version control program will return an appropriate log file reader (subclassed from a generic) to read the log file and spit out a canonical internal representation. So, of course, I can make BazaarLogFileReader and GitLogFileReader and hard-code them into the program, but I want it to be set up in such a way that adding support for a new version control program is as simple as plopping a new class file in the directory with the Bazaar and Git readers.

So, right now you can call "do-something-with-the-log --software git" and "do-something-with-the-log --software bazaar" because there are log readers for those. What I want is for it to be possible to simply add a SVNLogFileReader class and file to the same directory and automatically be able to call "do-something-with-the-log --software svn" without ANY changes to the rest of the program. (The files can of course be named with a specific pattern and globbed in the require call.)

I know this can be done in Ruby... I just don't how I should do it... or if I should do it at all.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You don't need a LogFileReaderFactory; just teach your LogFileReader class how to instantiate its subclasses:

```
class LogFileReader
  def self.create type
    case type 
    when :git
      GitLogFileReader.new
    when :bzr
      BzrLogFileReader.new
    else
      raise "Bad log file type: #{type}"
    end
  end
end

class GitLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "I'm a git log file reader!"
  end
end

class BzrLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "A bzr log file reader..."
  end
end
```

As you can see, the superclass can act as its own factory. Now, how about automatic registration? Well, why don't we just keep a hash of our registered subclasses, and register each one when we define them:

```
class LogFileReader
  @@subclasses = { }
  def self.create type
    c = @@subclasses[type]
    if c
      c.new
    else
      raise "Bad log file type: #{type}"
    end
  end
  def self.register_reader name
    @@subclasses[name] = self
  end
end

class GitLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "I'm a git log file reader!"
  end
  register_reader :git
end

class BzrLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "A bzr log file reader..."
  end
  register_reader :bzr
end

LogFileReader.create(:git).display
LogFileReader.create(:bzr).display

class SvnLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "Subersion reader, at your service."
  end
  register_reader :svn
end

LogFileReader.create(:svn).display
```

And there you have it. Just split that up into a few files, and require them appropriately.

You should read Peter Norvig's [Design Patterns in Dynamic Languages](http://norvig.com/design-patterns/) if you're interested in this sort of thing. He demonstrates how many design patterns are actually working around restrictions or inadequacies in your programming language; and with a sufficiently powerful and flexible language, you don't really need a design pattern, you just implement what you want to do. He uses Dylan and Common Lisp for examples, but many of his points are relevant to Ruby as well.

You might also want to take a look at [Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby](http://poignantguide.net/ruby/), particularly chapters 5 and 6, though only if you can deal with surrealist technical writing.

**edit**: Riffing of off Jörg's answer now; I do like reducing repetition, and so not repeating the name of the version control system in both the class and the registration. Adding the following to my second example will allow you to write much simpler class definitions while still being pretty simple and easy to understand.

```
def log_file_reader name, superclass=LogFileReader, &block
  Class.new(superclass, &block).register_reader(name)
end

log_file_reader :git do
  def display
    puts "I'm a git log file reader!"
  end
end

log_file_reader :bzr do
  def display
    puts "A bzr log file reader..."
  end
end
```

Of course, in production code, you may want to actually name those classes, by generating a constant definition based on the name passed in, for better error messages.

```
def log_file_reader name, superclass=LogFileReader, &block
  c = Class.new(superclass, &block)
  c.register_reader(name)
  Object.const_set("#{name.to_s.capitalize}LogFileReader", c)
end
```

Comment: I like it. I never thought of having the subclasses register themselves with the parent.

Comment: Just two quick suggestions: you seem to have a case of the Java-flu, in Ruby exceptions are raised with 'raise', not 'throw'. ('throw' is for generic light-weight non-local control-flow). And secondly, a case statement, especially one where the switch variable is named 'type', is a good ...

Comment: ... indicator for a refactoring towards polymorphism. Otherwise, very cool. So cool, in fact, that I just *had* to play around with it :-)

Comment: @Jörg You're right about throw/raise. I've been switching around between C++, Ruby, and Scheme recently, so I occasionally get something confused. Fixed it now. As for the case statement, the point is to dispatch between classes based on user input, so you're going to need that or the later hash.

Comment: You are right that in general, a case statement with a type parameter strongly indicates that you need some form of polymorphism.

Comment: You could replace the case with reflection, like I did (const_get("#{type.to_s.capitalize}LogFileReader").new), but you're right: that's probably overkill.

Comment: I saw that, and it is an option, but I generally prefer the simpler approach, especially if you need to support names that don't match the pattern exactly. If I were going to try and make it fancier, I'd go for something that expanded define_log_file_reader :git do ... end into the class definition.

Comment: Like I said, it's overkill. I am actually working on a plugin architecture right now, and I would *never* actually implement something like what I wrote in my answer. It is really just a demonstration of how to use reflection for automatic registration, but definitely *not* an endorsement.

Comment: Yep, that's fine, and you will see stuff like this in some code, so its good to have it explained. I added an example of what I was talking about, which I think is a little simpler and easier to understand than your method.

Comment: I am a little new to dynamic languages and type systems. Isn't it a bad idea for the base type to know about it derived types? For example in this case whenever a new logger type is added the base class needs to change?

Comment: As a Ruby Newby I really wish the "best" version of this example was in one place. I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with the @@subclasses array -- should it be in the final version?

Comment: Nitpick about this example: class variables (with `@@`) have surprising behavior in Ruby and should be avoided. Use a class instance variable instead—that is, use one `@` in a class context. You'll get a variable that's scoped to the class itself, but behaves in less weird ways. (In this case, one `@` on `@subclasses` would work perfectly.)

Comment: What is the final version? What is this line: "so not repeating the name of the version control system in both the class and the registration. " mean?

Answer (score 19):

This is really just riffing off Brian Campbell's solution. If you like this, *please* upvote *his* answer, too: he did all the work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Object; def eigenclass; class << self; self end end end

module LogFileReader
  class LogFileReaderNotFoundError < NameError; end
  class << self
    def create type
      (self[type] ||= const_get("#{type.to_s.capitalize}LogFileReader")).new
    rescue NameError => e
      raise LogFileReaderNotFoundError, "Bad log file type: #{type}" if e.class == NameError && e.message =~ /[^: ]LogFileReader/
      raise
    end

    def []=(type, klass)
      @readers ||= {type => klass}
      def []=(type, klass)
        @readers[type] = klass
      end
      klass
    end

    def [](type)
      @readers ||= {}
      def [](type)
        @readers[type]
      end
      nil
    end

    def included klass
      self[klass.name[/[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*/].downcase.to_sym] = klass if klass.is_a? Class
    end
  end
end

def LogFileReader type
```

Here, we create a global method (more like a procedure, actually) called `LogFileReader`, which is the same name as our module `LogFileReader`. This is legal in Ruby. The ambiguity is resolved like this: the module will always be preferred, except when it's obviously a method call, i.e. you either put parentheses at the end (`Foo()`) or pass an argument (`Foo :bar`).

This is a trick that is used in a few places in the stdlib, and also in Camping and other frameworks. Because things like `include` or `extend` aren't actually keywords, but ordinary methods that take ordinary parameters, you don't have to pass them an actual `Module` as an argument, you can also pass anything that *evaluates* to a `Module`. In fact, this even works for inheritance, it is perfectly legal to write `class Foo < some_method_that_returns_a_class(:some, :params)`.

With this trick, you can make it look like you are inheriting from a generic class, even though Ruby doesn't have generics. It's used for example in the delegation library, where you do something like `class MyFoo < SimpleDelegator(Foo)`, and what happens, is that the `SimpleDelegator` *method* dynamically creates and returns an anonymous subclass of the `SimpleDelegator` *class*, which delegates all method calls to an instance of the `Foo` class.

We use a similar trick here: we are going to dynamically create a `Module`, which, when it is mixed into a class, will automatically register that class with the `LogFileReader` registry.

```
  LogFileReader.const_set type.to_s.capitalize, Module.new {
```

There's a lot going on in just this line. Let's start from the right: `Module.new` creates a new anonymous module. The block passed to it, becomes the body of the module – it's basically the same as using the `module` keyword.

Now, on to `const_set`. It's a method for setting a constant. So, it's the same as saying `FOO = :bar`, *except* that we can pass in the name of the constant as a parameter, instead of having to know it in advance. Since we are calling the method on the `LogFileReader` module, the constant will be defined inside that namespace, IOW it will be named `LogFileReader::Something`.

So, what *is* the name of the constant? Well, it's the `type` argument passed into the method, capitalized. So, when I pass in `:cvs`, the resulting constant will be `LogFileParser::Cvs`.

And what do we set the constant to? To our newly created anonymous module, which is now no longer anonymous!

All of this is really just a longwinded way of saying `module LogFileReader::Cvs`, except that we didn't know the "Cvs" part in advance, and thus couldn't have written it that way.

```
    eigenclass.send :define_method, :included do |klass|
```

This is the body of our module. Here, we use `define_method` to dynamically define a method called `included`. And we don't actually define the method on the module itself, but on the module's *eigenclass* (via a small helper method that we defined above), which means that the method will not become an instance method, but rather a "static" method (in Java/.NET terms).

`included` is actually a special hook method, that gets called by the Ruby runtime, everytime a module gets included into a class, and the class gets passed in as an argument. So, our newly created module now has a hook method that will inform it whenever it gets included somewhere.

```
      LogFileReader[type] = klass
```

And this is what our hook method does: it registers the class that gets passed into the hook method into the `LogFileReader` registry. And the key that it registers it under, is the `type` argument from the `LogFileReader` method way above, which, thanks to the magic of closures, is actually accessible inside the `included` method.

```
    end
    include LogFileReader
```

And last but not least, we include the `LogFileReader` module in the anonymous module. [Note: I forgot this line in the original example.]

```
  }
end

class GitLogFileReader
  def display
    puts "I'm a git log file reader!"
  end
end

class BzrFrobnicator
  include LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "A bzr log file reader..."
  end
end

LogFileReader.create(:git).display
LogFileReader.create(:bzr).display

class NameThatDoesntFitThePattern
  include LogFileReader(:darcs)
  def display
    puts "Darcs reader, lazily evaluating your pure functions."
  end
end

LogFileReader.create(:darcs).display

puts 'Here you can see, how the LogFileReader::Darcs module ended up in the inheritance chain:'
p LogFileReader.create(:darcs).class.ancestors

puts 'Here you can see, how all the lookups ended up getting cached in the registry:'
p LogFileReader.send :instance_variable_get, :@readers

puts 'And this is what happens, when you try instantiating a non-existent reader:'
LogFileReader.create(:gobbledigook)
```

This new expanded version allows three different ways of defining `LogFileReader`s:

1. All classes whose name matches the pattern `<Name>LogFileReader` will automatically be found and registered as a `LogFileReader` for `:name` (see: `GitLogFileReader`),
2. All classes that mix in the `LogFileReader` module and whose name matches the pattern `<Name>Whatever` will be registered for the `:name` handler (see: `BzrFrobnicator`) and
3. All classes that mix in the `LogFileReader(:name)` module, will be registered for the `:name` handler, regardless of their name (see: `NameThatDoesntFitThePattern`).

Please note that this is just a very contrived demonstration. It is, for example, definitely *not* thread-safe. It might also leak memory. Use with caution!

Comment: Ok, some of this is definitely going over my head. What is going on in "def LogFileReader type"?

Answer (score 12):

One more minor suggestion for Brian Cambell's answer -

In you can actually auto-register the subclasses with an inherited callback.  I.e.

```
class LogFileReader

  cattr_accessor :subclasses; self.subclasses = {}

  def self.inherited(klass)
    # turns SvnLogFileReader in to :svn
    key = klass.to_s.gsub(Regexp.new(Regexp.new(self.to_s)),'').underscore.to_sym

    # self in this context is always LogFileReader
    self.subclasses[key] = klass
  end

  def self.create(type)
    return self.subclasses[type.to_sym].new if self.subclasses[type.to_sym]
    raise "No such type #{type}"
  end
end
```

Now we have

```
class SvnLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    # do stuff here
  end
end
```

With no need to register it

Answer (score 7):

This should work too, without the need for registering class names

```
class LogFileReader
  def self.create(name)
    classified_name = name.to_s.split('_').collect!{ |w| w.capitalize }.join
    Object.const_get(classified_name).new
  end
end

class GitLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "I'm a git log file reader!"
  end
end
```

and now

```
LogFileReader.create(:git_log_file_reader).display
```

Comment: Of all the code on this page, this one was the easiest for a Ruby noob like me to get. I also like that there's no storage of type names in the self.create, it feels more Rails-ish. +1

Comment: There's an issue with this method; you still require prior knowledge of the class name in calling code. That create method is so generic, it will happily return a new class of _any_ type so - something like `LogFileReader.create(:string)` returns a new empty String!

The advantage of using a registry of types is that the symbol :git used to find that reader class can be used to lookup other things. For example, a log rotator.

Comment: also, security wise, it is important to not allow the user to create anything at all... and if you are using Rails, ```name.to_s.split('_').collect!{ |w| w.capitalize }.join``` can be replaced with ```name.camelcase```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would make an extensible factory class.

```rb
module Factory
  class Error < RuntimeError
  end

  class Base
    @@registry = {}

    class << self
      def inherited(klass)
        type = klass.name.downcase.to_sym
        @@registry[type] = klass
      end

      def create(type, *args, **kwargs)
        klass = @@registry[type]
        return klass.new(*args, **kwargs) if klass
        raise Factory::Error.new "#{type} is unknown"
      end
    end
  end
end

class Animal < Factory::Base
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def walk?
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  def walk?; true; end
end

class Fish < Animal
  def walk?; false; end
end

class Salmon < Fish
end

duck = Animal.create(:cat, "Garfield")
salmon = Animal.create(:salmon, "Alfredo")
pixou = Animal.create(:duck, "Pixou") # duck is unknown (Factory::Error)
```