# Convert a class to a subclass on instantiation

Tags: ruby, oop, factory-pattern

I'm writing a framework for querying the [Mediawiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API). I have a `Page` class which represents articles on the wiki, and I've also got a `Category` class, which *is-a* `Page` with more specific methods (like being able to count the number of members in the category. I've also got a method `Page#category?` which determines if an instantiated `Page` object is actually representative of a Mediawiki category page, by querying the API to determine the namespace of the article.

```
class Page
  def initialize(title)
    # do initialization stuff
  end

  def category?
    # query the API to get the namespace of the page and then...
    namespace == CATEGORY_NAMESPACE
  end
end

class Category < Page
  # ...
end
```

What I would like to do is be able to detect if the user of my framework tries to instantiate a Mediawiki category using a Page object (ie. `Page.new("Category:My Category")`), and if so, instantiate a `Category` object, instead of a `Page` object, directly from the `Page` constructor.

It seems to me that this should be possible because it's reminiscent of single table inheritance in Rails, but I'm not sure how to go about getting it to work.

Comment: `category?` method in `Page` implies that ancestor class is aware of child class, which doesn't seem like good idea, OOP-wise. Also, can you clarify your last sentence a bit?

Comment: @Mladen: Not certain about Ruby syntax, but it seems he wants `Category foo = new Page()` instead of `Page bar = new Category()`.

Comment: Then he should probably take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746207/ruby-design-pattern-how-to-make-an-extensible-factory-class and, generally, google a bit about factory pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's bad idea to post a question right before I leave work and am away from a computer for 10 hours :p I'll edit my question for clarity.

Comment: @Mladen @Brian I hope that is clearer now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, couple of things:

You can't *convert* an instance of a class `A` to an instance of `A`'s subclass `B`. At least, not automatically. `B` can (and usually does) contain attributes not present in `A`, it can have completely different constructor etc. So, AFAIK, no OO language will allow you to "convert" classes that way.

Even in static-typed languages, when you instantiate `B`, and then assign it to a variable `a` of type `A`, it is still instance of `B`, it is not converted to its ancestor class whatsoever.

Ruby is a dynamic language with powerful reflection capabilities, so you can always decide which class to instantiate in the runtime - check this out:

```
puts "Which class to instantiate: "
class_name = gets.chomp
klass = Module.const_get class_name
instance = klass.new
```

So, no need for any conversion here - just instantiate the class you need in the first place.

Another thing: as I mentioned in the comment, method `category?` is simply wrong, as it violates OOP principles. In Ruby, you can - and should - use method `is_a?`, so your check will look like:

```
if instance.is_a? Category
  puts 'Yes, yes, it is a category!'
else
  puts "Nope, it's something else."
end
```

This is just a tip of the iceberg, there's lot more about instantiating different classes, and another question I have linked in the comment can be a great starting point, although some code examples there might confuse you. But it is definitely worth understanding them.

Edit: After re-reading your updated question, it seems to me that the right way for you would be to create a factory class and let it do the detecting and instantiating different page types. So, user wouldn't call `Page.new` directly, but rather call something like

```
MediaWikiClient.get_page "Category:My Category"
```

and `get_page` method would instantiate corresponding class.

Comment: I tried to make it clearer in my edit, but `Page#category?` isn't checking what type of class the object is, it's using a page's information to determine what namespace it falls under. I don't know where else I would put that...

Comment: Anyways, I guess I wasn't really familiar with the Factory pattern, but that does seem to be the way to go, thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize that you were talking about WikiMedia namespaces, not Ruby namespaces! :) Anyway, the place to check the WM namespace and instantiate appropriate class accordingly would be the factory. Of course, you _can_ put factory method into your `Page` class, again take a look at the other question - Brian Campbell gave great answer and code samples there.

Comment: "AFAIK, no OO language will allow you to "convert" classes that way"  Oh, there's always an exception!  :-)  In this case, CLOS has `CHANGE-CLASS` which does just that.  There are generic functions that can be used to control how exactly it works.

Answer (score 3):

Why not something like this? Being able to do that is a good enough reason to do it!

```
class Page
  def self.new(title)
    if self == Page and is_category?(title)
      Category.new(title)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def self.is_category?(title)
    # ... (query the API etc.)
  end

  def initialize(title)
    # do initialization stuff
  end

  def category?
    # query the API to get the namespace of the page and then...
    namespace == CATEGORY_NAMESPACE
  end
end

class Category < Page
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method that instantiate the class and returns the instance. 
This is know as [**Factory Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

```
class PageFactory
  def create(title) # the pattern uses "create".. but "new" is more Ruby' style
    namespace = title[/\A[^:]+(?=:)/]
     # matches the prefix, up to and excluding the first colon.
    if namespace == CATEGORY_NAMESPACE
      Category.new(title)
    else
      Page.new(title)
    end
  end
end

class ClientClass
  def do_something()
    factory = PageFactory.new
    my_page = factory.create('Category:Foo') 
    my_page.do_something()
  end
end
```

Comment: This won't work. `new` method in `PageFactory` is an instance method, and you are calling class method in `doSomething`. Also, it is not good idea to redefine `new` method, as it is used to instantiate the class on it has been called. BTW, Ruby convention is to use underscore_separated method names, not camelCased.