# Ruby Class Ineritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I've done a lot of searching about casting an object in Ruby, and can only find examples of casting a string to an integer or vice versa. I'm curious how to cast other, more complex objects..

For Example with these classes...

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :weight, :name
end

class Duck < Animal
  def speak
    'Quack'
  end
end
```

I would expect to be able to do something like the following.

```
irb> animal = Animal.new
irb> duck = (Duck)animal
irb> duck.speak
=> "Quack"
```

But I can't quite figure out how to do the casting as I would expect in Java or a similar language.

Comment: Is your last command in `irb` meant to be `duck.speak`?

Comment: You can turn `Animal` into a module, include it in the `Duck` class (or any other class which is not a sublcass of Animal), and _Animalify_ the class. I'm not familiar with casting so not sure if this is similar?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374065/convert-a-class-to-a-subclass-on-instantiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object in Ruby is created with a particular class and it will be destroyed with the same class, it never changes. You can't cast, either, all you can do is call functions which *convert*, a process that involves creating a new object or using another as a proxy.

In your case you can't cast, but you can create a duck with identical properties:

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :weight, :name

  def initialize(options)
    # Allow calling new with either an options hash, or another
    # animal that's intended to be cloned.
    case (options)
    when Animal
      @weight = options.weight
      @name = options.name
    when Hash
      @weight = options[:weight]
      @name = options[:name]
    end
  end
end

class Duck < Animal
  def speak(phrase)
    '%s says %s' % [ name, phrase.inspect ]
  end
end

animal = Animal.new(weight: 10, name: 'Bill')

duck = Duck.new(animal)
puts duck.speak('quack!')
```

A second option is to move the duck-like functionality to a separate module you can mix-in:

```
module ActsAsDuck
  def speak
    'Quack!'
  end
end

animal.extend(ActsAsDuck)
puts animal.speak
```

That mixes in any methods in that module into your object instance.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you should understand about Ruby is that the concept of type is not related to the class of an object. An object can respond to multiple interfaces other than it's original class (for example, by including modules or defining singleton methods). So, it's not necessary to typecast an object to have access to a particular interface. This means that is not important what an object **is**, the really important thing its what it's **does**.

This concept applies to strings and integers too. You don't typecast a string to integer, you ask a string object to create a new integer that is its idea of itself in this form.

If you want a further understanding about this, I suggest you to read about a concept known as **Duck typing**

In your case you can just instantiate a `Duck` object directly like this:

```
irb> duck = Duck.new
irb> duck.quack
=> "Quack"
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't cast an object to a subclass in java. You can only cast an object to its superclass or implemented interfaces. In ruby you don't need this casting. If you have an instance of `Duck` you can treat as an `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this close enough?

```
class Animal
  def subclass klass
    klass.new
  end    
end

class Duck < Animal
  def speak
    'Quack'
  end
end

animal = Animal.new
duck = animal.subclass(Duck)
duck.speak
  #=> "Quack"
```