# Dynamic registering classes in factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory

I'm currently trying to achieve something similar to what is proposed in the chosen answer of this question: [Ruby design pattern: How to make an extensible factory class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746274/469679)

```
class LogFileReader

@@subclasses = { }
  def self.create type
    c = @@subclasses[type]
    if c
      c.new
    else
      raise "Bad log file type: #{type}"
    end
  end
  def self.register_reader name
    @@subclasses[name] = self
  end
end

class GitLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "I'm a git log file reader!"
  end
  register_reader :git
end

class BzrLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "A bzr log file reader..."
  end
  register_reader :bzr
end

LogFileReader.create(:git).display
LogFileReader.create(:bzr).display

class SvnLogFileReader < LogFileReader
  def display
    puts "Subersion reader, at your service."
  end
  register_reader :svn
end

LogFileReader.create(:svn).display
```

The unit tests work flawlessly, but when I start the server no class is being registered. May I be missing something about how the static method call is working? When is the `register_reader` call made by each subclass?

Comment: You may need to make sure the file containing the class definitions is loaded.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: What can I do if the class is not being loaded?

Comment: You can start rails console to check if the classes is defined. rails s development , then type: defineded? LogFileReader, if it returns nil then the file is not loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Just ignore what I commented

Comment: I think you are running your app in development mode. In prod a similar code of mine works. I believe it is how rails behaves on development.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's question about when the classes call `register_reader`, it happens when the file is loaded. Add this code to an initializer to load the files yourself.

`Dir[Rails.root.join('path', 'to', 'log_file_readers', '**', '*.rb').to_s].each { |log_file_reader| require log_file_reader }`